# window.matchMedia for 3 intervals

Tags: javascript, matchmedia

I need for my web 3 intervals of matchMedia in javascript. I tried to use this:

```
if (matchMedia) {
var m1 = window.matchMedia("(max-width:640px)");
var m2 = window.matchMedia("(max-width:1024)");
m1.addListener(WidthChange);
m2.addListener(WidthChange);
WidthChange(m1,m2);
                }

                function WidthChange(m1,m2) {

                      if(m1.matches) {
                        console.log('ok1')
                      }else if(m2.matches){
                        console.log('ok2')
                      }else{
                        console.log('ok3')
                      }
```

it doesnt work. How do I have to modify it?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the "px" from:

```
var m2 = window.matchMedia("(max-width:1024)");
```

Also you don't want to declare `m1` and `m2` as the arguments to `WidthChange`, because that will override the `m1` and `m2` variables that you declared above. The argument to `WidthChange` will actually be a `MediaQueryListEvent`, which you're not using in your callback. So just declare it like this:

```
function WidthChange() {
```

Comment: so logicaly, my m1 should be an array of 2 values and i can delete m2. but it still doesnt work :)

Comment: i found a solution: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/matchmediamultiple.shtml